# Semi skew button css

Tags: css, button, skew

I would like to make this kind of button in CSS.
Could you help me to do this ?
Skew transformation is not enough...

[image: button semi skew]

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make use of pseudo elements of the button to make it look like the picture...

HTML

```
<button class="skew-btn">Skew Button</button>
```

CSS

```
.skew-btn
{
  padding:14px;
  border:none;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,#2196F3,#8BC34A);
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:600;
  font-size:26px;
  position: relative;
}
.skew-btn::before,
.skew-btn::after
{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  height:0px;
  width:0px;
  border:10px solid #fff;
}

.skew-btn::before
{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  border-bottom-color:transparent;
  border-right-color:transparent;
}
.skew-btn::after
{
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  border-left-color:transparent;
  border-top-color:transparent;
}
```

Make changes if needed..

Hope this helps

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/Ngxjwx?editors=1100)

```css
.skew-btn {
  padding: 14px;
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2196F3, #8BC34A);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 26px;
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
}

.skew-btn::before,
.skew-btn::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
}

.skew-btn::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

.skew-btn::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<button class="skew-btn">Skew Button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking exactly about it, but how can I make outline buttons with this effect?

Comment: If the answer solved your question... Mark it as answer.. `:)` @Romain

Comment: @JonesJoseph Thanks.. :D

Comment: @ChandraShekhar how could we do this effect with an outline button (no bakcground but only border) ?

Comment: @Romain, I need to give a try